# Express $\frac{\partial^2F}{\partial x^2} - \frac{\partial^2F}{\partial y^2}$ in terms of the partial derivatives of $F$ with respect to $u$ and $v$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If $F = F(u,v)$ and $u = x - y, v = x + y$, express $\frac{\partial^2F}{\partial x^2} - \frac{\partial^2F}{\partial y^2}$ in terms of the partial derivatives of $F$ with respect to $u$ and $v$. 
I'm not entirely sure how to approach this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 1,\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -1, \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 1, \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 1$

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} $

$= \frac{\partial F}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$
$= \frac{\partial F}{\partial v} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}$

$\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2} $

$= \frac{\partial}{\partial v}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x})\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial u}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x})\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$

$= \frac{\partial}{\partial v}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}) + \frac{\partial}{\partial u}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x})$

$= \frac{\partial}{\partial v}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial v} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}) + \frac{\partial}{\partial u}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial v} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial u})$

$=\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial v^2} +2\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial v\partial u} + \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial u^2}$, Assume F is continuous

Similarly,

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} $

$= \frac{\partial F}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial v} - \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}$

$\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2} $

$= \frac{\partial}{\partial v}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}) - \frac{\partial}{\partial u}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y})$

$=\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial v^2} -2\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial v\partial u} + \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial u^2}$, Assume F is continuous

Therefore,

$\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}  - \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y^2} = 4\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial v\partial u}$

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It's the mixed partial

$$4\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial u\partial v} = \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y^2}$$

Check this with the multivariable chain rule! **Edited**: Added missing multiple.

Comment: I believe you're missing a scalar multiple.

Comment: Indeed I was. I've edited the post, Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help.